# Need to create a triangle in the upper left of my div

Tags: css

I am trying to create a triangle in the upper left of my div that ignores the padding and does not push my text around.  I've gotten close, but it adheres to the padding and pushes the text.  Here is an image of what I have right now.

[image]

Now that blue triangle is following my 5px padding and it pushes the green box over so it isn't centered.
And here is my relevant HTML:

```
<li class="featured">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/brochure.jpg")" alt="brochure" />
        <div>
            <h2>Brochure</h2>
            <p>This is the text under the brochure.</p>
            View Brochure<br />
            Download PDF<br />
        </div>
    </li>
```

And the CSS:

```
section.mainWrap .brochures li.featured
{
    width: 42%;
    margin: 0 20px 15px;
    border: 2px solid #cccccc;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    padding: 4px;
}

    section.mainWrap .brochures li.featured .triangle 
    {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 50px 50px 0 0;
        border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
        float: left;
        z-index: 1;
    }

section.mainWrap .brochures li.flRight
{
    float: right;
}

section.mainWrap .brochures li h2
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

section.mainWrap .brochures li p
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 5px 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

section.mainWrap li.brochure
{
    width: 184px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    height: 390px;
}

section.mainWrap li.brochure img, section.mainWrap .brochures li.featured img
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Position the `li` as relative then position the 'triangle` as absolute. Frankly, I wouldn't use a div at all but a pseudo-element but that's another issue.

Comment: Have the container `position: relative` and the triangle `position: absolute`, that way it won't affect the rest of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `li` positioned relative and the triangle positioned absolutely in the top left. This ignores any padding. Then remove the `float`.

```
li.featured {
    position: relative;
    /* what you had before... */
}

li.featured .triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    NO FLOAT: LEFT!
    /* what you had before... */
}
```

The absolute positioning takes your triangle out of the regular flow of elements, and fixes it to a certain position no matter what. You need to position its parent relative, otherwise the triangle will stick to the top left of the *page*. [Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/cssref/css-positioning.html). [Resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Personally, I would use the [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) instead of a div. It wouldn't clutter up your markup.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, any object with `position: absolute` will be removed from the 'flow' of elements and will not push any other elements about. So make your triangle `position: absolute`. Like this:

```
section.mainWrap .brochures li.featured .triangle 
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now, an absolutely positioned element will be placed relative to the first parent element positioned either 'absolutely' or 'relatively'. If there aren't any, you will position the triangle relative to the whole page. Not what we want. So lets position the parent of the triangle, the li, relatively.

```
li.featured {
    position: relative;
}
```

This won't do anything to the `li`, it just allows the `li` to move if needed, and gives the triangle a reference.

To learn the detains about CSS positioning, check out this link:

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: @rvighne Provide an alternate link with the same information and I will swap it out.

Comment: Well, it *is* your answer, but... try MDN or Dottoro or Sitepoint or, best case, an actual w3c spec.